# MYSQL Select column name from other select

Tags: mysql, sum

I want to select `colum1 + column2 + column3` from one table but the problem is that the columns' names came from a script I can't change.

So I have

```
select column1,column2,column3 from table
```

but I need the sum of them. Can this be done? I tried:

```
select(select REPLACE(...))
```

it's not working.

Other way - no success, was:

```
select sum() from 
(
    select column1,column2,column3 from table
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sum, why not use:

```
SELECT (column1+column2+column3) FROM your_table
```

Comment: the problem is that the column names to be summed come from an input control. So I will have <code>SELECT sum(column1,column2,column3) from table</code>. This doesn't work. I can change and put the values in input control like `column1+` but then I will have `SELECT sum(column1+column2+column3+) from table`. wont work. So..I was thinking to make 2 selects `SELECT sum() from `
select column1,column2,column3 from table
) but it doesn't work because i have to specify the column name in sum condition and since i don't know how many columns do I have (user selection) I'm unable to ... sum

Comment: What server-side language is your input control using?

Comment: it is Jasper Server Reports. I'm not able to edit server side Input controls. I can only create them